Gradient of Minkowski functional
let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ denote some compact and convex set with the property that $0\in\mathring{A}$, where $2\leq n\in\mathbb{n}$, and consider the $\textbf{Minkowski functional}$
$$|x|_A := \inf \Big\{t>0: \frac{x}{t}\in A \Big\}, \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
There are some results concerning the differentiability of $|x|_A$, provided that $A$ has some smooth $C^1$ boundary. However, since differentiability is a local property, I am interested whether the $\textbf{Minkowski functional}$ $x_A$ is actually differentiable (or even of class $C^1$) in the set of points where $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: x\notin A\} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |x|_A >1\}$. Moreover, it would be very interesting to obtain the exact form of its gradient $\nabla |x|_A$ in this set. There is a similar post
Minkowski Functional differential, where it is stated that the gradient is given by
$$\nabla |x|_A = \frac{x}{|x|}, \qquad x\neq 0.$$
This is for example indeed true in the case where $A=B_1(0)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |x|\leq 1\}$, as the $\textbf{Minkowski functional}$ in this setting is explicitly given by $|x|_{B_1(0)}=|x|$, yielding the stated gradient. Moreover, a similar result holds true for the distance function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, given by $\text{dist}_A(x)=\inf\limits_{a\in A}|x-a| = |x-x_A|$ for some unique $x_A\in A$ (since $A$ is convex and in particular closed), there holds $\nabla \text{dist}_A(x) = \frac{x-x_A}{|x-x_A|}$.
However, is $\nabla |x|_A = \frac{x}{|x|}$ true for any set $A$ satisfying the above stated assumptions? I am as always very thankful for any input and help!
Note: By $|\cdot|$ I denote the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Because of homogeneity, if $|\cdot|_A$ is differentiable at $x$ then it is differentiable at $c\,x$ for every $c>0$; in particular, differentiability on the set you suggest implies differentiability at every $x\neq 0$.
Let us take some $x\neq0$ and set $x_1=x/|x|_A\in\partial A$. Let us suppose that there is  a unique linear form $l$ on $\mathbb R^n$  such that $l(x_1)=1$ and $l(y)\leq1$ for every $y\in A$ ($l$ always exists but it's not always unique; the differentiability fails if it's not unique). What it means geometrically: the hyperplane $T_{x_1}=\{y\in\mathbb R^n\mid l(y)=1\}$ is tangent to $\partial A$ at $x_1$.
The differential of $|\cdot|_A$ at $x$ is then $l$, and therefore the gradient is the vector $v$ given by $l(y)=v\cdot y$ for every $y\in\mathbb R^n$.

Thanks for your answer! I understand your reasoning. However, unfortunately it does not state what the gradient of $|x|_A$, i.e. $v$, actually looks like. Is there something more one could say?

not sure whether this explains it better, but: the gradient at $x$ is the same as at $x_1$, where it is the vector $v$ orthogonal to the boundary of $A$ and such that $v\cdot x_1=1$
